# how to call a parent member function in the overriding function?

Tags: c++

just asking what can I put instead of super.draw() to call the parent class function within the overriding function?

```
class base {
    void draw() {
    }
}
class derived {
    void draw() {
    super.draw();
    }
}
```

I know that for constructors the base constructor is automatically called at the derived constructor, I want basically the same thing for other methods. thanks

Answer (score 1):

First `dervied` needs to derived from `base` so that you can access its methods. Qualifying the call with `base::` will make the compiler look for the base class:

```
class derived : public base {
  void draw() {
    base::draw();
  }
};
```